# ReferenceError: chrome is not defined in Cordova android app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, google-chrome

I have wrapped angularjs website in cordova app. A particular button click that works fine on the browser throws ReferenceError: chrome is not defined" on a button click on Cordova mobile app (android platfrom)

```
07-04 00:24:56.055 26327-26327/com.xxxx.xxx I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(14630)] "ReferenceError: chrome is not defined", source: https://www.xxxx/xxxx/js/bundle.min.js (14630)
```

Am I missing a Chrome plugin ?

Comment: There's no "chrome" when using cordova. It tries to mimic a native app. Can we see the code that throws the error?

Comment: @Ivan Rubinson Thank you for comment, It breaks on function that traces out log lines, I would need a stack trace from Android Studio which i am not sure how to retrieve ..